# Create sub-matrices that have identical cell values

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with many rows and columns (`rxp`), I am trying to create a sub matrices that contains only those rows and columns that have identical cell values. For example

This is my matrix

```
   a  b  c  d 
a  0  1  1  1  
b  1  0  0  1
c  1  0  0  1
d  0  1  0  0
e  0  1  1  1
```

Here row `b`, `c` have identical values so the code should create, 1st sub matrix with only `b` and `c` rows and 2nd sub matrix with rows `a` and `e`

```
   a  b  c  d
b  1  0  0  1
c  1  0  0  1

   a  b  c  d
a  0  1  1  1 
e  0  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use.

```
 indx <- which(duplicated(m)) #m from @Richard Scriven post
```

returns a list of matrices

```
 lapply(indx, function(i) m[colSums(t(m)==m[i,])==ncol(m),])
 [[1]]
 #  a b c d
 #b 1 0 0 1
 #c 1 0 0 1

 [[2]]
 #  a b c d
 #a 0 1 1 1
 #e 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably there can be more than one set of repeated rows so if `m` is your matrix this creates a list of matrices in which each such matrix has rows that are repeated:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(m)
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, split(DF, do.call(paste, DF)))
```

Comment: Yep, that's more appropriate

Comment: @Grothendieck, I like to keep my dataset in a matrix format

Answer (score 2):

You could use `duplicated` in both directions.

```
m[duplicated(m) | duplicated(m, fromLast=TRUE),]
#   a b c d
# b 1 0 0 1
# c 1 0 0 1
```

Where `m` is

```
structure(c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), c("a", "b", "c", "d")))
```

Comment: I think `m[duplicated(m, fromLast=TRUE) | duplicated(m, fromLast=FALSE),]` would work without needing `sapply`.

Comment: Right you are!  I was using `&` and got mixed up.  Cheers!

Comment: @RichardScriven sorry i updated my question . The code should create separate sub matrices for each combination of identical values, right now m[duplicate....] is just creating one sub matrix with all identical combinations lumped together. I tired doing m[duplicated ..] on the m[duplicated...] ..that didnt work

Comment: That's why I think the other answer is more appropriate :)

Comment: @RichardScriven ah :) thats perfect